# Reading an image using the output of uigetfile

Tags: image, matlab

How to store the image into a variable (say `I`) retrieved using a `uigetfile()` command?
For instance,
I selected the image through

```
[FileName PathName] = uigetfile('E:\*.jpg','Select an image');
```

Now I want to store the selected image in the variable I.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the below code will work for you:-

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg','Select an image');
image=imread(strcat(PathName,FileName));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `imread`

```
  if ~isequal(FileName,0)
      I = imread(fullfile(PathName,FileName));
  end
```

The `isequal` is to test for user cancel click.

Comment: I got the following error
??? Undefined function or method 'equal' for
input arguments of type 'char'.